# Wordpress, store menu item length in php variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

Im creating a website with wordpress containing only one menu navigation bar. I am using the wp_nav_menu() wordpress function to create the menu and its items. I need to found out the menu item length and have it stored in a variable in php. Im fairly new to php and wordpress and im having trouble understanding its API in terms of solving this problem. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Using [wp_get_nav_menu_items](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

```
 <?php $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args ); ?>
```

Updated:

Look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35411/how-to-count-nav-menu-items):

Comment: How do i convert $items into an integer?